# Charset formatting problem

Tags: locale

I have a problem on my server, it's not recognizing the symbols, i already tried doing a lot of stuff on system locale, but nothing has fixed this.

I need to turn this (output of "ls" command):

```
'Um Maluco no Peda'$'\347''o'
'Um Milh'$'\343''o de Coisas'
'Voc'$'\352'' Nunca Esteve Sozinha - O Doc de Juliette'
'Vov'$'\364'' e Eu'
```

Into this:

```
'Um Maluco no Pedaço'
'Um Milhão de Coisas'
'Você Nunca Esteve Sozinha - O Doc de Juliette'
'Vovô e Eu'
```

Comment: So, what _is_ your locale? What does `locale` output?

Answer (score 1):

Your files have ISO88591 charset names (one byte per accentuated characters instead of 2), then they don’t fit the default charset which is UTF-8 nowadays.

To make `ls` not to escape these characters, you could type `LANG=fr_FR.iso88591` (replace fr and FR by your language code, probably PT), then `ls` will not escape the accentuated ISO88591 characters. The available values are listed with `localedef --list-archive`. If none of the values are iso88591, you may need to add them with `dpkg-reconfigure locales` (Debian based system only).

But if you use a UTF8 terminal, characters won’t be printed normally… you should also use an iso88591 terminal.

An alternative to an iso88591 terminal is to type `ls|iconv -f iso88591 -t utf-8` (Less practical).

Could you print us the `$LANG` value before changing its value (this will give the national code you should use instead of `fr`. Or type `locale` which is more complete). The `localedef --list-archive` output can be useful too. (Your environment also : KDE, Gnome…)

Note : if you plan to use these files in a UTF-8 environnement, you may need to rename them and avoid switching to an ISO88951 mode.